# How to place figure/table without caption in ConTeXt?

Tags: floats, captions, context

When I am trying to

```
\placefigure[here]{none}{\externalfigure....
```

I am getting figure with caption "none" instead of figure without any caption.

How to `\placefigure` without a caption in

```
mtx-context     | ConTeXt Process Management 0.60
mtx-context     |
mtx-context     | main context file: /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/context.mkiv
mtx-context     | current version: 2013.05.28 00:36
```

Comment: `placefigure[here,none]{}{\externalfigure[...]}`

Comment: Works for me, you can post your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using MkII syntax. In MkIV, `none` as a caption is no longer treated as a magic word. To disable caption, you need to add `none` as a `location` parameter. So use:

```
\placefigure[here, none]{}{\externalfigure[...]}
```

or the key value driven interface:

```
\startplacefigure[location={here,none}]
    \externalfigure[....]
\stopexternalfigure
```